# How to solve "Error: nebula-net not found"?

Tags: nebula-graph

NebulaGraph version: v3.2.0. An error is reported when using Docker to deploy database, the console client as below:

```
[72165315@bdsp-submit-prd-10-193-10-7.v-bj-4.vivo.lan:/home/72165315]
§ docker run -rm -ti --network nebula-docker-compose_nebula-net vesoft/nebula-console:nightly -addr xx.xx.xx.xx -port 9700 -u root -p nebula
docker: Error response from daemon: network nebula-docker-compose _nebula-net not found.
```

how to solve problem and run sucessfully?

Comment: Is this enough information for anybody to reproduce the issue? (i.e. is this a [mre]?)

Comment: @user yes, the error message is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates that you are trying to connect to a network called "nebula-docker-compose_nebula-net" in Docker, but the Docker daemon could not find this network.

There could be several reasons for this:

The network may not have been created yet. To create a network in Docker, you can use the docker network create command.

The network may have been deleted. To delete a network in Docker, you can use the docker network rm command.

The network name may be incorrect. Make sure that you have typed the network name correctly and check if the network name is being used elsewhere.

There may be a problem with your Docker daemon, causing it to not work properly. Try restarting the Docker daemon or your computer to see if it resolves the issue.